# Which Apple Networking Api to use for UDP multicasting and unicasting?

Tags: ios, swift, udp, multicast, unicast

New to iOS development and networks in general. Developing a game-show-type app where a 'host' device needs to multicast to 'contestant' devices. The contestant devices also need to be able to respond. Very little information is actually being passed along but speed does matter hence the use of UDP.

I've been researching some of the commonly used networking api's for apple devices: network.framework, CocoaAsyncSocket, Multipeer-Connectivity, BSD sockets, etc. Overall, I'm leaning towards just using the high-level network.framework but the lack of examples and resources is making the decision difficult. Any advice would be appreciated.